# Removing file extensions using .htaccess causes errors

Tags: apache, .htaccess, lamp, bitnami

Earlier today, I was trying to remove the `php` file extension when people visit my website using `.htaccess`. (Sort of like https://tecadmin.net/remove-file-extension-from-url-using-htaccess/)
Below is my `.htaccess` file:

```
#Remove php file extensions
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

The code seems to be doing its job, but I quickly noticed a problem. `http://example.com/page` and `http://example.com/page.php` works perfectly fine, but when I visit `http://example.com/page/`, the server returns an internal server error. (500)

I tried looking online on how to fix this, but I came up empty. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. If you are getting a 500 error code, you can get more info from the Apache's log (/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log), can you edit your message and include that info?

Comment: What response do you want to see when requesting `/page/` (with a trailing slash)? The correct response would arguably be a 404, although you could choose to _remove_ the trailing slash with an external redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
>
> RewriteEngine on 
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
> ```

Your first and last rules are doing the same sort of thing (appending the `.php` extension via an internal rewrite), however, they are doing it slightly differently and arguably incorrectly. And you certainly don't need both.

The 500 error when requesting `/page/` is caused by a rewrite-loop. The first rule rewrites the request to `/page/.php`. The *last* rule then rewrites the request a 2nd time to `/page/.php.php` and then again to `/page/.php.php.php` etc. etc. Because `REQUEST_FILENAME` is `/page` in all cases and so `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` (in the *condition*) is not necessarily the same as `%{REQUEST_URI}.php` (the URL being rewritten to).

Try the following instead:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Remove php file extensions

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

The redirect that removes the `.php` extension should probably be a 301 (permanent) redirect, once you have confirmed that this works as intended.

The `NC` flags on the `RewriteRule` directives were superfluous.

There's no need to backslash-escape literal dots when used inside a regex character class. The dots carry no special meaning here. So, `[^.]` is the same as `[^\.]`. (Although you escaped one and not the other.)

This now checks for the same file `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php` that is being rewritten to in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string, ie. `$1.php`.

NB: I've explicitly disabled MultiViews to ensure that these directives are not overridden by mod_negotiation.

This will now result in a 404 should `/page/` (with a trailing slash) be requested. If this should return the same as `/page` then this should be implemented as an additional redirect, to remove the trailing slash.

Comment: Thanks! I will check this out.

Comment: @Leo How did you get on with this?

Comment: Sorry for the late response! It works nicely.